# extJS: How to center vertically inside a card layout (fiddle inside)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a card layout setup and the second item in the card I have tried wrapping inside a panel and setting it to a vbox and align center so that it is centered in the middle of the screen.Its not working.

Anyone have any ideas ?

I have managed to configure a fiddle

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12c9

If i remove the layout, then it reappears but of course its not centered in the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `width` of the panel.

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12ca

Comment: Thanks, yep that fixed it.